# dmesg -n7 has no effect in virtual terminal

Tags: tty, terminal-emulator, dmesg

When I type `dmesg -n7` in console (ie when I switch to tty1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) I can see all debugging messages (new disks plugged in, etc).

When I type `dmesg -n7` in virtual terminal (terminal emmulator) when logged in in my Desktop Environment, I see no dmesg messages.

How can I see `dmesg` messages in virtual terminal ?

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
dmesg -w
```

(follow mode) shows the contents of the message buffer and waits for new messages. To get an effect similar to the virtual consoles, *i.e.* a terminal you can continue working in but where kernel activity is printed out regardless of anything else that's happening, you can run that command in the background

```
dmesg -w &
```

If your `dmesg` doesn't support follow-mode, you can simulate it as long as you don't mind clearing the buffer:

```
sudo dmesg -c
```

prints the buffer and clears it (it needs to run as `root` to clear the buffer), and you can set up a sub-shell to do this repeatedly:

```
sudo sh -c "(while :; do dmesg -c; sleep 5; done)"
```

Place that in the background and you're done.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately my dmesg  version does not have the `-w` option (util-linux 2.20).

Comment: That's a shame, the feature is [quite old](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=0fd12a9697c2e01e3c2e1e558ff027cd2947ee94) (July 2012).